# creating many objects with collision properties. JAVA

Tags: java, swing

I have a simple program with three rectangles: one that can move with the push of the arrow keys, and two that are already moving back and forth on their own.

When the 'player' rectangle and top red collide, the player driven rectangle gets put back to (0,0). When I try to collide the player rectangle with the bottom red rectangle, it does not have those collision properties and I have no idea why.

What am I missing?

```
import java.awt.*;//needed for graphics
import javax.swing.*;//needed for JFrame window
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class javaapplication23 extends JFrame implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    public static int x = 0;
    public static int y = 0;
    public static int x2 = 100;
    public static int y2 = 100;

    public javaapplication23() {//constructor for JPanel
        add(new JP());

    }//close Jpanel Contructor

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javaapplication23 w = new javaapplication23();
        w.setTitle("MIKE IS AWESOME");
        w.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        w.setVisible(true);
        w.addKeyListener(w);
    }

    public class JP extends JPanel {//start JPanel CLass

        public JP() {
            Container c = getContentPane();
            c.setBackground(Color.white);//backgraund color can be changed

        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {//opens paint method
            super.paint(g);

            player(g, x, y);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            enemylevel1(g, x2, y2);

            Rectangle enemyblocks = new Rectangle(x2, y2, 25, 25);
            Rectangle player = new Rectangle(x, y, 25, 25);
            enemyblocks.contains(x2, y2);
            player.contains(x, y);

            if (player.getBounds().intersects(enemyblocks.getBounds())) {

                x = 0;
                y = 0;
            }

            pause(1);

            repaint();

        }//close paint method

    }//close JPanel Class

    public static void pause(int time) {

        try //opens an exception handling statement
        {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }  //captures the exception
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_RIGHT) {
            x += 20;//global variable controlling right movement
            repaint();
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_LEFT) {
            x -= 20;//global variable controlling left movement
            repaint();
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_UP) {
            y -= 20;//global variable controlling up movement
            repaint();
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_DOWN) {
            y += 20;//global variable controlling down movement
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void player(Graphics g, int x, int y) {

        g.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);

    }

    public void enemylevel1(Graphics g, int x, int y) {

        g.fillRect(x2, y2, 25, 25);
        g.fillRect(x2, y2 + 100, 25, 25);

        if (x2 < 200 && y2 == 100) {

            x2 += 1;
        }
        if (x2 == 200 && y2 >= 100) {

            y2 += 1;
        }
        if (x2 <= 200 && y2 >= 101) {

            x2 -= 1;
        }
        if (x2 == 100 && y2 <= 101) {

            y2 -= 1;

        }
        pause(10);
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: `pause(1);` <- Don't block the EDT

Comment: im sorry, im pretty new to programmimng. How is that blocking the EDT and how could i unblock it?

Answer (score 2):

Start by having a look at [Working with Geometry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html), this will allow you to reduce much of the code complexity.

Basically, a enemy is just a `Rectangle`, `Graphics2D` can paint these without to much of an issue.  What you need to do is create an instance which can also update it's position based on your needs

```
public class Enemy extends Rectangle {

    private int xDelta;

    public Enemy(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y, 20, 20);
        if (x == 0) {
            xDelta = 1;
        } else {
            xDelta = -1;
        }
    }

    public void update(Rectangle bounds) {
        x += xDelta;
        if (x < bounds.x) {
            x = bounds.x;
            xDelta *= -1;
        } else if (x > bounds.x + bounds.width - width) {
            x = bounds.x + bounds.width - width;
            xDelta *= -1;
        }

    }

}
```

So, this creates a single unit of work, which is isolated from everything else and carries it's own logic with it.  This makes updating it, painting and generally working with much simpler.

Next, you need to create a `List` of these

```
public class Bounce extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    private List<Enemy> enemies;
    //...

    public Bounce() {

        enemies = new ArrayList<>(5);
        int y = 100;
        for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
            int x = (index % 2 == 0) ? 0  : 200;
            Enemy enemy = new Enemy(x, y);
            enemies.add(enemy);

            y += 60;
        }
```

This creates a `List` of `Enemy`s which are distributed evenly within the container.

Now, we need to paint them....

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {//opens paint method
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();

    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

    for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
        g2d.fill(enemy);
    }
}//close paint method
```

*nb: General convention suggests that you should override `paintComponent` when you want to perform custom painting*

But they don't move, that kind of sucks.  So we need a way to, on a regular bases, update the position of the enemies...

First, we create a simple method which we can call to update the enemies, remember, they are capable of updating themselves, we just need to tell them when

```
public void updateState() {

    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(20, 20, 200, 200);
    for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
        enemy.update(bounds);
    }

}
```

Remember, the `Enemy` is self contained, it knows how to update itself based on the constraints you have provided.

And now, we need to call this method on a regular bases...

```
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        updateState();
        repaint();
    }
});
timer.start();
```

Okay, this will schedule a callback every 40 milliseconds which will allow us to call the `updateState` method and `repaint` the component.  This is neat because it won't block the Event Dispatching Thread (making our program look like it's hung) but which notifies us within the context of the EDT, making it safe to update the UI from within - WIN/WIN :)

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

Okay, but that doesn't solve the collision...

The player is also a `Rectangle`, so why not use the same concept we have with the enemies...

```
public class Bounce extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    private List<Enemy> enemies;
    private Rectangle player;
    //...
    public Bounce() {

        player = new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 30);
        enemies = new ArrayList<>(5);
        //...
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {//opens paint method
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        drawPlayer(g2d);
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

        for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
            g2d.fill(enemy);
            if (player.intersects(enemy)) {
                player.x = 0;
                player.y = 0;
            }
        }
    }//close paint method

    public void drawPlayer(Graphics2D g) {

        g.fill(player);

    }
```

Which ends up with something like...

[image: Enemies]

This allows you to add/remove enemies as you want and also change the way in which the enemies move, simply and easily

An my "awesome" test code...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Bounce extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    private List<Enemy> enemies;
    private Rectangle player;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Bounce());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public Bounce() {

        player = new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 30);
        enemies = new ArrayList<>(5);
        int y = 100;
        for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
            int x = (index % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 200;
            Enemy enemy = new Enemy(x, y);
            enemies.add(enemy);

            y += 60;
        }

        setBackground(Color.white);//backgraund color can be changed
        Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                updateState();
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(240, 400);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {//opens paint method
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        drawPlayer(g2d);
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

        for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
            g2d.fill(enemy);
            if (player.intersects(enemy)) {
                player.x = 0;
                player.y = 0;
            }
        }
    }//close paint method

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_RIGHT) {
            player.x += 20;//global variable controlling right movement
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_LEFT) {
            player.x -= 20;//global variable controlling left movement
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_UP) {
            player.y -= 20;//global variable controlling up movement
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_DOWN) {
            player.y += 20;//global variable controlling down movement
        }
    }

    public void drawPlayer(Graphics2D g) {

        g.fill(player);

    }

    public void updateState() {

        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(20, 20, 200, 200);
        for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
            enemy.update(bounds);
        }

    }

    public class Enemy extends Rectangle {

        private int xDelta;

        public Enemy(int x, int y) {
            super(x, y, 20, 20);
            if (x == 0) {
                xDelta = 1;
            } else {
                xDelta = -1;
            }
        }

        public void update(Rectangle bounds) {
            x += xDelta;
            if (x < bounds.x) {
                x = bounds.x;
                xDelta *= -1;
            } else if (x > bounds.x + bounds.width - width) {
                x = bounds.x + bounds.width - width;
                xDelta *= -1;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow this was awesome, thank you so much! this helped me a lot! if i could upvote your comment i would but i just joined this website:/

Comment: OP is incredibly lucky to have such a detailed answer on such a poor question.

Comment: @Qix The OP is lucky they actually made an effort at solving their own problem (IMHO)