# Collision detection between two images in java

Tags: java

I need to know when the rocket hit the meteor, img2 is the meteor and img is the rocket

```
g.drawImage(img, posX - img.getWidth(this)/2, posY - img.getHeight(this), this);
        g.drawImage(img2,posX1 - img2.getWidth(this), posY1 - img2.getHeight(this),this);
        System.out.println(posY-img.getWidth(this));
        System.out.println(posY1);
      }
      public void colid (){
        if (posY1+img.getWidth(this)>= posY-img2.getWidth(this) ){

            System.out.println("teste");
        }
```

Comment: Is it a test or a teste?

Comment: Please fix your code, as it stands, it will not compile (are there missing lines above the first curly bracket?)

Comment: this is only a part of the code. Test

Comment: Do you just want to do simple rectangular collision, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251027/creating-many-objects-with-collision-properties-java/30251268#30251268), [exmaple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153110/brick-collision-java/21153384#21153384), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927189/detecting-collision-of-two-sprites-that-can-rotate/20928531#20928531), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261767/java-ball-object-doesnt-bounce-off-of-drawn-rectangles-like-its-supposed-to/13263022#13263022)

Comment: Or do you want to know when the non-alpha pixels collide, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23332096/how-to-detect-if-two-images-collide-in-java/23332186#23332186)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [Rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) for every object like for a rocket or meteor

and there is a Rectangle method you can use

```
boolean intersects(Rectangle r)
Determines whether or not this Rectangle and the specified Rectangle intersect.
```

so you could check

```
if (rectangleA.intersects(rectangleB){
 System.out.println("Colliosion!!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(posX - img.getWidth(this)/2, posY - img.getHeight(this), img.getWidth(this), img.getHeight(this));
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(posX1 - img2.getWidth(this), posY1 - img2.getHeight(this), img2.getWidth(this), img2.getHeight(this));

        boolean collision = r1.intersects(r2);
```

Note: You are dividing the width with 2 in the first image and not the second. Maybe it is as it should be but just want to let you know if it is not.

Comment: He gave almost certain but it was only in the center even changing the image position