# Collision Detection - Unintersecting

Tags: java, swing, awt, collision-detection

I work on a little project trying to understand how collision detections is handled by engines and I did the detection part for a simple 2 square in java. I don't use a graphics library or meshes it is just java swing and java awt. This is what I have:
https://vimeo.com/642432871

I have no idea to start implementing the part where the squares collide without going one trough another.

Comment: *"I have no idea .."* You also have no question.

Comment: At the end of the day, you'll want to learn what the APIs provide you (based on what ever framework you're using), as, personally, taking the time to do all the maths is a lot of work. If you're really interested, you could probably pull the source code and read through them.

Comment: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153110/brick-collision-java/21153384#21153384); [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251027/creating-many-objects-with-collision-properties-java/30251268#30251268); [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927189/detecting-collision-of-two-sprites-that-can-rotate/20928531#20928531); [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261767/java-ball-object-doesnt-bounce-off-of-drawn-rectangles-like-its-supposed-to/13263022#13263022) - as some examples based on the Shapes APIs